# MSB3721 error when run CUDA12.0 in VS2019

Tags: c++, cuda, visual-studio-2019, nvidia

windows10

CUDA version: 12.0.1

VS2019 16.10.3

When I run the code in cuda-samples(https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/tree/master/Samples/5_Domain_Specific/nbody), I get the error:

```
MSB3721 命令“"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.0\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_21,code=\"sm_21,compute_21\" --use-local-env -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\bin\HostX86\x64" -x cu   -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.0\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.0\include"  -G   --keep-dir x64\Debug  -maxrregcount=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static  -g  -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -D_DEBUG -D_CONSOLE -D_MBCS -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /FS /Zi /RTC1 /MDd " -Xcompiler "/Fdx64\Debug\vc142.pdb" -o E:\amaterials\program\CUDA\CudaTest\CudaTest\x64\Debug\kernel.cu.obj "E:\amaterials\program\CUDA\CudaTest\CudaTest\kernel.cu"”已退出，返回代码为 1。   CudaTest    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 12.0.targets   799
```

[image]

Can anyone help me solve it?

Comment: MSB3721 is a generic error message. It is VS telling you a tool it ran failed. Nothing more. You need to look at the detailed output of nvcc to understand what error occurred.  Also please don't post screenshots of errors or code. They can't be searched for

Comment: Can you paste here the actual error text?

Comment: Easy to help if you (1) copy error message as text and paste it instead of the image (IDE supports copy as text) and (2) share some minimum reproducible code (project, in your case). Most likely you mixed the versions of CUDA (in samples and yours).

Comment: Thanks guys! I am new here, not very good at asking questions. I will take your advice in the future. :)

Answer (score 1):

I know why now!

This article describes the same question as mine. I accidentally selected the "beta". I don't even know when and why :).

https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/error-msb3721-when-building-cuda-sample-and-programs-in-vs2019-widnows10-64bit/196483

Hope it helps!

(But I still don't know how it affects CUDA.)